# How can I automatically save all on build in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio when I trigger a build it automatically saves all files first. I want the same behavior in VS Code, but couldn't find a way to do it short of writing my own extension. Is there any simple method I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you're asking, but will also accomplish what you want: you could enable the auto-save feature:

```json
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
```

After using IntelliJ for a while, I managed to get rid of my habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> after every second typed-out word, for the most part (since it has auto-save by default). I was happy to find out that VSCode support this somewhat less stressful workflow too.

---

Other than that, there's also a `Files: Save All` command you've probably already found.

I'm actually not sure you can do this with the extension API right now - you can definitely trigger the "save all" command easily, but you'd need to be notified of when a build occurs, and I couldn't find any events for this. I think it will definitely be possible after [#15179](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15179) is resolved though, which should allow extensions to participate in builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building using a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), then you can use the `task.saveBeforeRun` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=To%20modify%20user%20settings%2C%20you,keyboard%20shortcut%20(Ctrl%2B%2C).).

If you're using the CMake Tools extension, use the `cmake.saveBeforeBuild` [setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings).

You can also manually use one of the commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) with "save all" in their names (use whichever is appropriate for what you want), or the associated [keyboard shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) (you can also customize those keyboard shortcuts).